# How to switch two images for a perfect animation?

Tags: c#, image

I have two images switch for a simple walking animation. In my solution I use the x coordinate of the character to switch. But it's not what I want, because it is swithing too fast. What can I do to make the character "walk slower"?

```
if (player.MovementX % 2 == 0)
{
    image = Image.FromFile(player.imageFileName);                
}
else
{
    image = Image.FromFile(player.imageFileName2);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how the code you've posted relates in any way to the problem at hand.  I cannot understand your variables or method names because they are not in English.  You have no provided a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: show the calling code. what kind of timing is in use? a loop, a timer, ... and you should really load both images into memory beforehand. `Image.FromFile` will access the storage every time.

Comment: The code is simple to understand. If the x-coordinate is even, one image is shown, otherwise the other.

Comment: Please, load those images only once, and save them in some local variable, instead of making a new image object that rereads them from disk on _every single step your character makes_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply divide the x-coordinate by the desired step length

```
if ((player.MovementX / stepLength) % 2 == 0) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) It worked till stepLength = 3. The image swithed on every third. 3,6,9. However with stepLength = 4. It switch on 1 and 2, like this: 1,2 - 4,5 - 7,8.

Comment: It work for me. `MovementX` must be an `int` (or `long`). If it is not convert it. `((int)player.MovementX / stepLength) % 2`. Because we need an integer division. I.e. 4/4 = 1, 5/4 = 1, 6/4=1, 7/4=1, 8/4=2, 9/4=2, 10/4=2, 11/4=2, 12/4=3 ... The integer division truncates the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the images are switching too quickly when the character moves, you could try something like this to make it slower.

```
if (speler.BewegingX % 10 < 5)
{
    image = Image.FromFile(speler.imageFileNaam);
}
else
{
    image = Image.FromFile(speler.imageFileNaam2);
}
```